# How to zip and encrypt a file from DOS or PowerShell command using a securely stored password

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

I need to run a script in Windows server, ideally in DOS or PowerShell that allows me to download some files from a file repository to the server, compress the files with a password, and then upload to Amazon S3 for storage.

The script does the following:

1. Downloads data to a local folder, say c:\temp\mydata
2. Compresses the data. (I'm using 7-zip)
3. Executes an AWS CLI command to upload to S3.

I want to add in 2. the ability to use a password on the file, but I don't want that password to be visible on the script.

Is there any command that can use a password stored in the system somewhere, that can be retrieved from the DOS or PowerShell command, to use it while compressing, so that the password is not in plain sight?

Comment: Take a look at `Read-Host -AsSecureString`, `ConvertFrom-SecureString`, and `ConvertTo-SecureString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the password as plain text and convert the batch file to an exe file. Here is a great tool I use for it: http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?pid=b2e

Hope this helps!

Comment: That means the password will sit in plain text in the executable. Very insecure.

Comment: How can something be in plain text in an executable file? For your information an executable file is a binary file and it won't be in 'plain text'.

Comment: It's quite trivial. Simply Open the file in a binary file viewer, or use a utility like [strings.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) to dump the strings from the file.